# How do I parse a specific json data response?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, parsing

Been yanking my hair out the past few days.

I want to parse just a single piece of data from a string response using Get method.

My php code I'm working with:

```
 <?
    include "function.php";
    $request_rest->setMethod("GET");
    $result = $request_rest->execute();
    $response_status = $result[0];
    $json_response_data = $result[1];
    if ($response_status == "200") {
        echo $json_response_data;
    } else {
        echo $response_status ." - connection failure";
    }
    ?>
```

The results I get:

```
      {"data1":"value1",
       "data2":"value2",
       "data3":"value3",
       "data4":"value4",
       "data5":"value5"}
```

I only want to display "value3" for my output but instead I'm getting the full string response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the key of the data you want (the data3 part) you can json_decode the json_response_data:

```
if ($response_status == "200") {
  $decoded = json_decode($json_response_data);
  echo $decoded['data3'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Decode the JSON data](http://php.net/json_decode) and access it like any other array:

```
$data = json_decode($json_response_data, TRUE);
echo $data['data3'];
```